# Deploy an Azure VM of image Windows 10 Pro (with license)

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, deployment, windows-10, licensing

I am trying to create a Windows VM in Azure using the Azure Portal.

The image (base OS for the VM) I selected for the VM was :
`Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2 - Gen 1`

But the licensing for this Image differs from windows server images.

Licensing section in basic tab of Azure VM creation also differs according to the image selected:

[image: When selected image : Windows Server 2019 Datacenter - Gen 1]

[image: When selected image : Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2 - Gen 1]

In the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) page, I can choose the option `Windows OS` before selecting a VM Size. And we can check the pricing for the licence too. But does that `Windows OS` refers to only `Windows server` ? Or does it mean Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise too?

When searched in the Microsoft documentation, they are mentioning `Windows 10 Enterprise` only as Windows 10 image. I couldn't find deploying VM with `Windows 10 Pro, version 20H2` anywhere.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/windows-desktop-multitenant-hosting-deployment

> Users must have one of the below subscription licenses in order to use
> Windows 10 images in Azure. If you do not have one of these
> subscription licenses, they can be purchased through your Cloud
> Service Partner or directly through Microsoft.
>
> Eligible subscription licenses:
>
> - Microsoft 365 E3/E5
> - Microsoft 365 F3
> - Microsoft 365 A3/A5
> - Windows 10 Enterprise E3/E5
> - Windows 10 Education A3/A5
> - Windows VDA E3/E5

It is very confusing.

Is it possible to deploy an Azure VM with `Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2` image ?

If yes, how should i get the license?

- Can i purchase that Windows 10 pro licence with the Azure VM itself by paying more?
- Or should i get a Microsoft 365 E3 license? (But the Microsoft 365 E3/E5/F3 all provides Windows 10 Enterprise licence with it, not windows 10 pro!)
- Would Purchasing a new Windows 10 pro retail license for this azure VM work? If yes, when this VM is removed, Can i reuse that windows 10 pro license for any of my on-premises machine or for any other azure VM?
- Or can i use/transfer an existing Windows 10 pro license (that i already used for my on-premises machine) to this Azure VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy a Windows 10 VM in Azure you must already own Windows 10 Enterprise E3/E5 per user or Windows Virtual Desktop Access per user licences for Windows 10, you cannot use an Azure provided licence.

You cannot use Windows 10 Pro, it must be Enterprise. [Details here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/windows-desktop-multitenant-hosting-deployment).